# Visual Studio 2010 Web application did not reflect User Name and User Domain at client machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I have created a web application using Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows Server 2008 with the code as follows:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Environment.UserDomainName.ToString() + " " + Environment.UserName.ToString();

    }
```

I notice that when I debug / run the web application at the server, the user and the user domain is correctly display on the web application via the `Label1` label box.

However, when I publish the web application to IIS and access it from a client machine. The user and the user domain is not display at all.

The client machine is connected to another domain and so I was wondering if this affect the code above from displaying the user name and the user domain at the client machine?

Appreciate any help offered.

Comment: You've probably got Anonymous Authentication enabled on the IIS server. Ensure only Windows Authenticaion is enabled.

Comment: make sure that IIS authentication "Windows Authentication" is enabled and that you disable "Anonymous Authentication".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post below:

[Getting a users DOMAIN/username from a web application](http://forums.asp.net/t/1121780.aspx/1)

[How can I get the domain name and username?](http://www.justskins.com/forums/how-can-i-get-37645.html)

Best Regards

Comment: I tried the solution with `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` working but it display the System account. Both `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and `Page.User.Identity.Name` return me null value. The last one `Request.ServerVariables["logon_user"].ToString()` give me an error - `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. `

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

Comment: Strange, I got the following error - `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.HttpContext.User.get'`

Comment: @Jack Use `HttpContext.Current.User`, not `HttpContext.User`.

Comment: @RB. I used the `HttpContext.Current.User` return me null as comment in one of the answer.

Comment: @Jack You're problem is almost certainly that you have anonymous authentication enabled in IIS - please check this before trying anything else...

Comment: @RB. At last all the problem is solved, I am able to see the user name and the domain.

Comment: @Jack What was the problem in the end? Was it anonymous authentication being enabled?

Comment: @RB. It is not only the anonymous authentication problem but a full load of configuration problems. (That also include that one need to close the IIS Manager in order to reflect new installation changes) Took me too long to solve but glad that it is over for the time being.